# Setting initial value of a Vuetify checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a Vue JS app that uses a Vuetify checkbox. I am unable to set the initial value to checked.

```html
<v-checkbox
  v-else-if="input.type == 'checkbox'"
    false-value="0"
    true-value="1"
    v-model="input.val"
    :error-messages="form.errors[field]"
>
```

When `input.val` is equal to `1` i expect the checkbox to start off checked. However the checkbox will not start off checked.

I have also tried adding the props:

```
:value="input.val"
:input-value="input.val"
```

None of these affect the starting state of the checkbox though. If `input.val` starts off as `1`, why does this box not start off checked?

```html
<v-checkbox
  v-else-if="input.type == 'checkbox'"
  false-value="0"
  true-value="1"
  :value="input.val"
  :input-value="input.val"
  v-model="input.val"
  :error-messages="form.errors[field]"
>
  <template #label>@{{ input.hint }}</template>
</v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `:` or `v-bind` for numbers, if you use  `v-bind:true-value` it`s work fine. Example [on codepen](https://codepen.io/spigel-jack/pen/PryPpg?&editable=true&editors=101).

**Example**

```
<div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox1"
                        v-bind:false-value="0"
                        v-bind:true-value="1"
                      :label="`Checkbox 1: ${checkbox1.toString()}`"></v-checkbox>
          <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox2" :label="`Checkbox 2: ${checkbox2.toString()}`"></v-checkbox>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      checkbox1: 1,
      checkbox2: 0
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Not sure why you think there's a bug in Vuetify, it just needs the types to match. Without the `v-bind` the `true-value` and `false-value` are treated as strings and won't be equal to the numbers in the data.

Comment: Yes, but if you using `true-value` and `false-value` without binding not update the v-checkbox input value, not the `v-model` value. The `v-model` value updated, but the input value not.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you use `true-value` and `false-value` without the `v-bind` then the values will just be strings so you'd also need the initial value in the data to be a string, `checkbox1: '1'`. So long as everything uses the same types it works fine.

Comment: Sorry I was inaccurate. Yes, you right, but without binding it is string. For arrays, objects you need to use binding.

Comment: this works too in vuetify3. i'm using mysql and it sends a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `false-value` and `true-value`, and using `false` or `true` telling it if it should be checked in `value`.

Comment: There are both `false-value` & `true-value` properties. See documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls

Comment: I looked at the docs, I don't see any properties in regular or next version.

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't selecting 'v-checkbox' from the dropdown after you visit the link. Selection controls are all listed on that link, and the initial props displayed are for `v-radio-group`.