# Vuetify checkbox not correctly displaying value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I bind a Vuetify checkbox to a value. But even though the value equals the specified "true-value", the checkbox is not displayed as checked. For confirmation, I display the model value and its type below the checkbox. Working with the native true/false values is not an option as the data backend expects the values 1 and 0.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I know this a duplicate of [Setting initial value of a Vuetify checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918647/setting-initial-value-of-a-vuetify-checkbox), but no answer or comment helped and I am not allowed to comment.

```html
<v-checkbox 
  v-model="getActiveQuote.isSDIS"
  v-bind:false-value="'0'"
  v-bind:true-value="'1'"
></v-checkbox>
{{ getActiveQuote.isSDIS }} {{ typeof getActiveQuote.isSDIS  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works as expected when I try it out:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const getActiveQuote = ref() // base object has to be a ref
    getActiveQuote.value = {isSDIS: '1'} // or you could pass this through reactive()
    return {
      getActiveQuote
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
    <v-checkbox 
      v-model="getActiveQuote.isSDIS"
      false-value="0"
      true-value="1"
    ></v-checkbox>
    {{ getActiveQuote.isSDIS }} {{ typeof getActiveQuote.isSDIS  }}
   
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But what if the value is not a ref but an attribute of a regular JS object (that e.g. comes from a REST call to a backend)?

Comment: Oh, then you have to put the object into a ref or pass it through `reactive()`, Have a look at the updated template. Add more code to your question for a more specific answer - what happens with `getActiveQuote` (which apparently is not a function).

Comment: Reactivity is the keyword here. Thanks.